# Writing a query that requires getting information from 2 different tables in a database in php

Tags: php, postgresql

I am writing my last query for my homework, but I am stuck on it right now. This query requires me to take information from 2 tables instead of 1. I am confused on how to get this information from both tables and how to put them together. Here is the description of the query that I am trying to write.

```
For each country display the capital city name and the percentage of the population that lives in   
the capital for each country. Sort the results from largest percentage to smallest percentage.
```

For this query I believe I am going to have to get the population of the whole country, then get the population of the capital city and then divide them in order to get the percantage of the population that lives in the capital. I just cant wrap my head around how I am going to perform this math especially when the data comes from 2 different tables. Thanks for the help in advance. Here are the tables that I am going to use for this query

```
Table "lab2.city"
Column    |         Type          |                     Modifiers                     
--------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------
 id           | integer               | not null default nextval('city_id_seq'::regclass)
 name         | character varying(35) | not null default ''::character varying
 country_code | character(3)          | not null default ''::bpchar
 district     | character varying(20) | not null default ''::character varying
 population   | integer               | not null default 0
Indexes:
"city_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
"city_country_code_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (country_code) REFERENCES country(counry_code) ON DELETE CASCADE


 => \d country
                           Table "lab2.country"
 Column      |         Type          |               Modifiers              

-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------
country_code    | character(3)          | not null default ''::bpchar
name            | character varying(52) | not null default ''::character varying
continent       | continent             | not null
region          | character varying(26) | not null default ''::character varying
surface_area    | real                  | not null default 0::real
indep_year      | smallint              | 
population      | integer               | not null default 0
life_expectancy | real                  | 
gnp             | real                  | 
gnp_old         | real                  | 
local_name      | character varying(45) | not null default ''::character varying
government_form | character varying(45) | not null default ''::character varying
head_of_state   | character varying(60) | default NULL::character varying
capital         | integer               |
```

Comment: Did you googled `JOIN IN SQL` ?

Comment: @user3699735: You think you're clever, eh? Modifying your old post so it can't be found as a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25916257/1

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP is saying "gimme teh codez". In addition the OP has posted this question previously. The OP has provided no data and has not setup a sqlfiddle.

Comment: @user3699735: Why do you expect somebody to do your homework if you don't show even the slightest motivation to learn? And why do you try to cheat?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get information from two tables you must join them on a common factor, in this case the `country_code`. Additionally you can perform the percentage calculation right in the query as I have done here. Finally you can order the aliased column in PostgrSQL by using the column's number from it's order in the query. Here it is the second column, hence 2.

```
SELECT `lab2`.`city`.`name`, ((`lab2`.`city`.`population`/`lab2`.`country`.`population`) * 100) AS `Population Percentage`
FROM `lab2`.`city`
JOIN `lab2`.`country`
ON `lab2`.`city`.`country_code` = `lab2`.`country`.`country_code`
WHERE `lab2`.`city`.`id` = `lab2`.`country`.`capital`
ORDER BY 2
```

One note, there is nothing in the city table to indicate capital unless the capital value in the country column is supposed to be the id of the city. I have modified the query to use that, not knowing if it is correct.